# Random Forest does not accept feature names

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to train a random forest, but have issues with the naming of variables:

```
library("randomForest")

f <- "~ var1_testTRUE + var2_root_subj. + var3_test.en-US"
rf <- randomForest(as.formula(f), data=dtrain, ntree=10, nodesize=10)
```

This is the error message:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : objeto 'var3_test.en' no encontrado
```

It's not clear to me why `-US` is not appended to the feature name.

How to fix it?

Comment: `var3_test.en-US` is a non-syntactic name so you need to surround it with backticks

Comment: @DiceboyT: make this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var3_test.en-US` is a non-syntactic name, so you need to surround it with backticks. You can see that as written your formula isn't being parsed how you want:

```
as.formula("~ var1_testTRUE + var2_root_subj. + var3_test.en-US")
# ~var1_testTRUE + var2_root_subj. + var3_test.en - US
```

With backticks it gets parsed correctly:

```
as.formula("~ var1_testTRUE + var2_root_subj. + `var3_test.en-US`")
# ~var1_testTRUE + var2_root_subj. + `var3_test.en-US`
```